# Mutually self-referencing type parameters compiling under JDK6 but not 7?

Tags: java, generics, types

The following code compiles using JDK6 (I tried **1.6.0_24**)

```
class XY<A extends XY<A, B>, B extends XY<B, A>> { }
```

But compiling under JDK7 (e.g. **1.7.0**), I get this error:

```
XY.java:1: error: type argument B is not within bounds of type-variable A
class XY<A extends XY<A, B>, B extends XY<B, A>> {
                                      ^
  where B,A are type-variables:
    B extends XY<B,A> declared in class XY
    A extends XY<A,B> declared in class XY
1 error
```

Can anyone point as to *whether this was an intentional change* to Java's generics?

Comment: It compiles fine for me with Java  >= 1.7.0_02

Comment: Really? Are you sure? I'm using **1.7.0_02-b13**

Comment: This is fun. It's compiling in Eclipse with Java 7 features.   I tried it via command line and sure enough I get the same compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that's a bug that comes from OpenJDK and is caused by a bug in type-variable substitution.

It appears when you switch generic variables for examples:

```
class XY<A extends XY<A, B>, B extends XY<B, A>> { } 
class XY<A extends XY<B, A>, B extends XY<A, B>> { }
```

It doesn't appear in this:

```
class XY<A extends XY<A, B>, B extends XY<A, B>> { } 
class XY<A extends XY<B, A>, B extends XY<B, A>> { }
```

you can see another example here: http://old.nabble.com/Apparent-generics-compilation-bug-new-to-Java-1.7-td33378164.html